# What tools do you use to deploy Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, deployment

I'm hoping someone can shed light on which tool(s) you use to deploy your builds out to your web servers: [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl), web farm framework, a flunky copying files using [XCOPY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For our builds we use [CruiseControl.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CruiseControl) and [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) with a few custom tasks to control our load balancer during a deployment.

You can read about all of the tools we use to build Stack Overflow in *[Stack Overflow Architecture Update - Now at 95 Million Page Views a Month](http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/3/stack-overflow-architecture-update-now-at-95-million-page-vi.html)* (published 2011-03-03).

We are looking at making some changes to our build, but the details have not been worked out yet.

Comment: Have there been any updates to the deployment process since then? I'm just curious what options are out there for .net apps.