# How is Stack Overflow developed, tested and deployed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, development, testing, deployment

I am not talking about technologies or stacks.

Stack Overflow is one of the largest [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) applications around, and I am interested in development methodology, testing methods and deployment methods used and employed for such a large site running over multiple servers. And multiple variations of the site.

- What kind of user interface testing, regression testing, etc. is employed?
- How do you deploy to multiple servers?
- How are database updates / changes tested and deployed to the live environment?
- Any link or posts with details around this will be appreciated.

If this is in the incorrect place, apologies.

**Edit:
Links that are helpful, but not enough depth and breadth of detail (and not current):**

- *[Does Stack Overflow have automated tests?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33761)*
- *[What tools do you use to deploy Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100565)*
- *[Which tools and technologies are used to build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369)*

Comment: That almost sounds like something that would be better for a blog post than for Meta.

Comment: Testing is done by deploying the code and letting the hordes of users loose on the code :)

Comment: Just sift through [Nick answers here on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135201/nick-craver?tab=answers), there are many hidden gems among them where he reveals information about the work done behind the scenes. For example [database related answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A135201+is%3Aanswer+database).

Comment: I don't know if *they* test the code, but [sometimes they *test us* if we pay attention](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71780/lol-debugging-are-we-so-homepage-alerts-false).